# How omit page number on some pages in fancyhdr?

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr

Using `fancyhdr` how can I achieve that on specific pages the page number is omitted. For example, in the minimal example I want the page number to appear on the third page and the page number of the third page should be 1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{HEADER
}
\begin{document}
 \blindtext
 \newpage

 \blindtext
 \newpage

 \blindtext
 \newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Either use different page styles or use conditionals for your `\cfoot` etc. stuff. What is `HEADER` supposed to be? The page number?`

Comment: No, the header is supposed to be a name and address. On the pages where the page number should appear it is supposed to be default style, that is centered in the foot. Actually exactly as in the min expl just no page number on page 1 and 2 and page number on page equal to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{fancy}



\chead{HEADER
}
\cfoot{\ifnum\value{page} > 2 \the\numexpr\value{page}-2 \fi}
\begin{document}
 \blindtext
 \newpage

 \blindtext
 \newpage

 \blindtext
 \newpage
\end{document}
```

**Edit** Corrected version, with `hyperref` links working

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\chead{}%
\cfoot{}%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\blindtext
\newpage

\blindtext

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chead{HEADER}%  Better here
\cfoot{\ifnum\value{page} > 0 \thepage \fi}

\section{My first section}
\blindtext
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good, only I need to reset the page number on the third page to be =1. Otherwise exactly what I need. Hoe can I do the resetting?

Comment: @lpdbw: Changed it already, because I posted the first version. But it's not correct still, because the wrong pagenumber would be entered in the ToC

Comment: OK, saw it now, you were too quick :-) Thx a lot. I do not need a ToC, so for my purpose it's fine. But maybe for other people it might be more helpful if you can fix it.

Comment: @lpdbw: As soon as you have a `ToC` my first version is wrong, especially when `hyperref` is used. I suggest to use completely empty header for the first two pages and shift `\chead{}` to the appropiate place, after `\pagenumbering{arabic}`